# How to fix 'float' object not iterable in this code

Tags: python, formula

I am trying to write this formula:

> J = 1/2m∑i(x−y)2

In Python code, but it is giving me an error I don't know why.

I defined `x` and `y` values and wanted to calculate `J` but when I write code for `J` it gives me an error.

```
x = 0.5
y = 1
J = [sum(x**2 - y**2)]*1/6
```

It gives an error:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: `sum` is for making a sum of all items in a list, not a mathematical sigma sum. In your case, your x and y are always the same == are not iterable. Also, your formula is way different than what you wrote, even if `sum` means sigma...

Comment: I am trying to write the cost optimization formula from Andrew Ng machine learning course,it be best if you help me.

Comment: Are both x and y guaranteed to have the same amount of numbers?

Comment: Yes James it does,as x is the numbers of features in predicted set and y is np of features in actual set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sum build-in method is meant to work with iterable (lists for example) 
the execution of your code is like this:

1. evaluate `x**2 - y**2` which is a float than
2. this float will be an argument for sum function and so you got the error you could use:

   `J = (x**2 - y**2) / 6`

if  x and y are lists for example:

```
x = [0.5, 1, 1.5] 
y = [1 ,2, 3]
```

you can try:

```
J = sum(i**2 + j**2 for i, j in zip(x, y)) / 6
```

Comment: Thanks yeah but can you guide if the value of x is [0.5 , 1 , 1.5] and y is [1 ,2 , 3],then what should I do?

Comment: x and y should have the same length?

Comment: @SibtainReza check now my update

Comment: yes it does,as x is the numbers of features in predicted set and y is np of features in actual set

Comment: New update checked working perfect :)